# I need to make a "mosaic" - but very simple

Tags: python, image, request, photo, mosaic

The best code for mosaic I've found you can see at this page:
https://github.com/codebox/mosaic

However, the code doesn't work well on my Windows computer, and also I think the code is too advanced for what it should do. Here are my requirements I've posted on reddit:

1)   The main photo already has reduced number of colors (8)

2)   I have already every image associated with colour needed to be replaced (e.g. number 1 is supposed to replace black pixels, number 2 replaces green pixels...)

3)   I need to enlarge the photo by the small photo's size (9 x 9 small photos will produce 81 times bigger image), which should push the pixels "2n" points away from each other, but instead of *producing a n x n same-coloured area around every single one of them (this is how I believe enlarging works in general, correct me if I'm wrong)*, it will just colour the white spaces with unrecognized colour, which is not associated with any small photo (let's call that colour C)

4) Now all it needs is to run through all non-C coloured pixels and put an image centered on that pixel, which would create the mosaic.

---

Since I'm pretty new to Python (esp. graphics) and need it just for one use, could someone help me with creating that code? I think that code I got inspired with is too complicated. Two things I don't need:

1) "approximation" - if the enlargement is lesser than needed for 100% quality (e.g. the pictures are 9x9, but every side of the original photo can be only 3 times larger, then the program needs to merge some pixels of different colours together, leading to quality loss)

2) association colour - picture: my palette of pictures is small and of colours as well, I can do it manually

For the ones who didn't get what I mean, here is my idea: https://ibb.co/9GNhqBx

Comment: Please post a complete set of sample images (your 8 colour photos, plus your 8-colour master image), or I'll have to make test data as well as writing the program.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1z3ExFgGM6iKNQLucfTyYv5FiMTYeT3km - the colour choice is not very promising, however.

Comment: Hello, you'll need to save mainpic as a PNG, not a JPG, or you'll have many more than 8 colours in there. Also, how do you know which smallpic to use for each mainpic colour?

Comment: . I used the online converter to reduce the number of colours. It's  true that they wanted me to post picture in JPG, but as soon as the number of  colours is reduced, it shouldn't increase (e.g. when saving it as PNG) ... 2. It can be done automatically (complicated)  or manually, as I want. It's up to you.

Comment: The Palette of colours is kinda dull and it is hard to match, choose it yourself (the colours don't have to necessarily match, just one smallpic = one colour is all I need)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a quick go using [pyvips](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import os
import pyvips

if len(sys.argv) != 4:
    print("usage: tile-directory input-image output-image")
    sys.exit(1)

# the size of each tile ... 16x16 for us
tile_size = 16

# load all the tile images, forcing them to the tile size
print(f"loading tiles from {sys.argv[1]} ...")
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    tiles = [pyvips.Image.thumbnail(os.path.join(root, name), tile_size, 
                                    height=tile_size, size="force") 
             for name in files]

# drop any alpha
tiles = [image.flatten() if image.hasalpha() else image
         for image in tiles]

# copy the tiles to memory, since we'll be using them many times
tiles = [image.copy_memory() for image in tiles]

# calculate the average rgb for an image, eg. image -> [12, 13, 128]
def avg_rgb(image):
    m = image.stats()
    return [m(4,i)[0] for i in range(1,4)]

# find the avg rgb for each tile
tile_colours = [avg_rgb(image) for image in tiles]

# load the main image ... we can do this in streaming mode, since we only 
# make a single pass over the image
main = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[2], access="sequential")

# find the abs of an image, treating each pixel as a vector
def pyth(image):
    return sum([band ** 2 for band in image.bandsplit()]) ** 0.5

# calculate a distance map from the main image to each tile colour
distance = [pyth(main - colour) for colour in tile_colours]

# make a distance index -- hide the tile index in the bottom 16 bits of the
# distance measure
index = [(distance[i] << 16) + i for i in range(len(distance))]

# find the minimum distance for each pixel and mask out the bottom 16 bits to
# get the tile index for each pixel
index = index[0].bandrank(index[1:], index=0) & 0xffff

# replicate each tile image to make a set of layers, and zoom the index to
# make an index matching the output size
layers = [tile.replicate(main.width, main.height) for tile in tiles]
index = index.zoom(tile_size, tile_size)

# now for each layer, select pixels matching the index
final = pyvips.Image.black(main.width * tile_size, main.height * tile_size)
for i in range(len(layers)):
    final = (index == i).ifthenelse(layers[i], final)

print(f"writing {sys.argv[3]} ...")
final.write_to_file(sys.argv[3])
```

I hope it's easy to read. I can run it like this:

```
$ ./mosaic3.py smallpic/ mainpic/Use\ this.jpg x.png
loading tiles from smallpic/ ...
writing x.png ...
$
```

It takes about 5s on this 2015 laptop and makes this image:

[image]

I had to shrink it for upload, but here's a detail (bottom left of the first H):

[image]

Here's a google drive link to the mosaic, perhaps it'll work: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J3ofrLUhkuvALKN1xamWqfW4sUksIKQl/view?usp=sharing

And here's this code on github: https://github.com/jcupitt/mosaic

Comment: Thank you, but could you help me with installing the pyvips? It seems very complicated on Windows, and I don't know why it cannot be provided as a folder. They say "pip install" everywhere which is supposed to make things easy but makes it harder for me.

Comment: There are notes here: https://github.com/libvips/pyvips#non-conda-install ... download the zip, `pip install pyvips`, then put those couple of lines at the start of your program.